# Where can I find the global values in an x86-64 assembly file?

Tags: c, assembly, static, global-variables, reverse-engineering

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int i[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

int main(){

    int iLength = sizeof(i)/sizeof(i[0]);
    
    for (int x = 0; x < iLength;){
        printf("%d", x);
        x+=1;
    }
}
```

Here is the code. I am trying to locate where the array is initialised in ASM.

I easily identified what it looks like when I initialised 'I' in the main function. Should it look the same when it's initialised outside a function?

Comment: Static variable's are "initialised" by putting the indicated values in a data section in the executable. No run-time code is emitted, since the data is loaded by the loader. On a Unix-like system, if the static variable has no initializer (so that the initial value is all 0), then the variable is placed in a `.bss` section, which doesn't have a value representation in the executable (the length is sufficient). Objdump may be useful (again, if you have a Unix-like system to play with).

Comment: I downloaded IDA Free and started using that instead of radare2. I was looking in .bss and elsewhere but I just found it difficult to abstract the white noise. 

PS. I am learning how code in C is structured in assembly.

Comment: If you look at the compiler's asm output (not binary), you'll find directives like `.data` to switch sections and `.long 1,2,3,4,5` or equivalent: https://godbolt.org/z/MqsE85EfW.  There is no machine code, just data in the `.data` section.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.